# C# Windows Form - Problem input validation Calculator

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, calculator

I am having a little problem with validation on my calculator, I would like when I press enter or all other characters except numbers ,it would notify me of an error.
Basically, I would like that when I type a letter or special character with the keyboard I get an error returned

I am using windows form, I attach below my code:

```
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double result;
    String oper = "+";





    private void button_minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // label1.Text += minus_click.Text;
        num1 = double.Parse(label1.Text);
        oper = "-";
        label1.Text += oper;
        label1.Text = "";






    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button15.Text;





    }









    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button16.Text;


    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button5.Text;
    }





    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button4.Text;
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += division_click.Text;
    }

    private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button7.Text;
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }









    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button_AC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = String.Empty;
        label3.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button16.Text;
    }

    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button17.Text;
    }

    private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button7.Text;
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button8.Text;
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button9.Text;
    }

    private void button11_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button11.Text;
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button12.Text;
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button6.Text;
    }

    private void buttonPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += buttonPoint.Text;


        num1 = (double)Convert.ToDecimal(label1.Text);
        num2 = (double)Convert.ToDecimal(label1.Text);



    }











    private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += moltiplication_click.Text;
    }

    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += addiction_click.Text;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button3.Text;
    }

    private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button5.Text;
    }











    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void addiction_click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label1.Text += addiction_click.Text;
        num1 = double.Parse(label1.Text);

        oper = "+";
        label1.Text = string.Empty;
        label3.Text = String.Empty;

    }

    private void moltiplication_click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label1.Text += moltiplication_click.Text;


        num1 = double.Parse(label1.Text);
        oper = "*";
        label1.Text += oper;
        label1.Text = "";
        label3.Text = String.Empty;




    }

    private void division_click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        num1 = double.Parse(label1.Text);
        oper = "/";
        label1.Text += oper;
        label1.Text = "";
        label3.Text = String.Empty;

    }

    private void buttonPIùOMENO_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = double.Parse(label1.Text);


    }

    private void buttonPERCENTUAL_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //num1 = (double)Convert.ToDecimal(label1.Text);
        oper = "%";
        label1.Text += oper;

        label3.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void button3_Click_0(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += button3.Text;

    }




    private void equals_click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
        label1.Text = label1.Text;


        switch (oper)
        {

            case "+":
                result = num1 + num2;
                label3.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
                break;
            case "-":
                result = num1 - num2;
                label3.Text = Convert.ToString(result);

                break;
            case "*":
                result = num1 * num2;
                label3.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
                break;
            case "/":

                result = num1 / num2;
                label3.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
                break;
            case "%":
                num2 = (double)Convert.ToDecimal(label3.Text);
                result = num1 % num2;
                label3.Text = result.ToString();
                break;


        }

        label3.Text = result.ToString();



    }

    private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


     public bool ValidationEmptyNumber(String s)
    {

        bool isNumber = true;


        while (isNumber)
        {
            label1.Text = num1.ToString();
            label1.Text = num2.ToString();

            return isNumber = true;

            if (label1.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter a number");
                return isNumber = false;
            }



        }

    }
      public bool ValidationOnlyNumbers(String s) {
        bool isNumber;

                Regex regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");
                Match match = regex.Match("impossible to insert letters or special characters");


        while (isNumber = true)
        {
            label1.Text = num1.ToString();
            label1.Text = num2.ToString();

            return isNumber;

            if (match.Success)
            {
                label1.Text = match.Value;
                MessageBox.Show(match.Value);

            }
            {

            }




        }

        {

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is all the code relevant to your problem? (<= rhetorical question tbh) Do you have questions about handling pressed keys or only about the checks in your last function? You should edit the question to be much more precise on where you have issues.

Comment: no, I'm having a little difficulty understanding the controls, that is, I would like when I type a letter or any other special character to return the error

Comment: yes, basically I have a problem with the 2 functions, I would like to try to make it so that when I type "enter" or letters, special characters I get an error notification.
So it should only accept numbers